# Cursor:pointer not working on input type file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change cursor type on input type=“file”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537223/change-cursor-type-on-input-type-file)

This is my jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/3zNMK/

This class already has a cursor but not working:

```
.file
{
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

I want that even though a hover is made on textbox inside input type file, it should change to hand icon. But it is not working.

Any way to change this behavior?

Comment: @Andy doesn't make a difference.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112643/jquery-cursor-pointer-on-a-file-input-possible and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537223/change-cursor-type-on-input-type-file are related.

Comment: @Andy: Yes, true. But that shouldn't make difference. The main issue of having cursor:hand on textbox still remains.

Comment: @Jack there are tons of duplicates on stackoverflow...(see aziz's links) did you try to search first?

Comment: I think its impossible to do so to a file field

Comment: @Andy — `.class:hover { cursor: pointer; }` means "Given an element of class `class` with the mouse over it, when the mouse is over it use the `pointer` cursor". `:hover` is redundant.

Comment: read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7554845/the-cursorpointer-property-doesnt-apply-to-file-upload-buttons-in-webkit-brows

Comment: try ::-webkit-file-upload-button { cursor:pointer; }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try some manipulation like this

**HTML**

```
<span class="file-wrapper">
  <input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" />
  <span class="button">Choose a File</span>
</span>
```

​
**CSS**

```
.file-wrapper {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.file-wrapper input {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 100px;
  filter: alpha(opacity=1);
  -moz-opacity: 0.01;
  opacity: 0.01;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.file-wrapper .button {
  background: #333;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 4px 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3zNMK/21/)**

Comment: A bit late to the party — can you comment on the 1% opacity rather than 0? I couldn't find any browser that rejected or overruled the 0…

Answer (score 0):

You used `cursor:hand;` on your fiddle, this is outdated.

if you use `cursor:pointer;`, the hand cursor will appear when you hover your input.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get what you mean. What is outdated? hand or pointer? I've used pointer.

Comment: You've used `hand` on the fiddle but that doesn't make a difference either. This should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

`cursor:hand` is understood by few old browser, like IE6. User `cursor:pointer` instead